# use mysql to replace one custom field value with another custom field value

Tags: custom-field, mysql

I have two custom fields, and both have numeric values:

tnid_01

tnid_01old

Custom Field 'tnid_01' exists for all posts.

Custom Field 'tnid_01old' only exists for some posts.

I am trying to replace the value of 'tnid_01' with the value of 'tnid_01old',  but only if 'tnid_01old' exists.

This is what i have so far, but i get a mysql error:

```
Update wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)(
SELECT post_id, 'tnid_01', meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key='tnid_01old'
);
```

thx

Comment: In the end i used WebElaine's approach with update_post_meta
Here is the code i used:
$args = array( 'meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'tnid_01old',)));
$cpt_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($cpt_query->have_posts()) : while ($cpt_query->have_posts()) : $cpt_query->the_post(); 
$tnid = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tnid_01old', true);
update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tnid_01', $tnid );
endwhile; endif;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do this with MySQL alone, since you'd need to save values and reuse them. Here's a PHP version.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
// select all the old postmeta
$oldData = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'tnid_01old'");
// make sure we have results
if($oldData) {
    // loop through each result
    foreach($oldData as $meta) {
        // save post ID and meta value
        $meta_post_id = $meta->post_id;
        $metavalue = $meta->meta_value;
        // update 'tnid_01' value
        $wpdb->update(
            // table name
            'wp_postmeta',
            // value to set
            array(
                'meta_value' => "$metavalue"
            ),
            // condition to meet: match same post ID but new meta key
            array(
                'post_id' => $meta_post_id,
                'meta_key' => 'tnid_01'
            )
        )
    }
}
?>
```

If you're on a low-traffic site, you could temporarily paste this into a theme template file and load whatever page uses that template, then make sure to remove this code so it's not hitting the database again. Or a more proper way would be to have it run within wp-admin.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason your query is not working is that you have omitted the `SET` statement.

I'm not sure if you are looking for a one-time solution, or something programmatic you can reuse, but see if this gives you the desired results:

`UPDATE wp_postmeta SET 'tnid_01' = 'tnid_01old' WHERE 'tnid_01old' IS NOT NULL`

Comment: this gives me a sql error. could you please be a little more specific with the query?
i think its missing something like:
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = 'tnid_01' = 'tnid_01old' WHERE meta_key LIKE 'tnid_01old' IS NOT NULL